# Menu opens only after 4 clicks

Tags: java, android

For some odd reason, the menu in my android [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.core.sandbox.activities&hl=en) is only opened after 4 clicks on the menu button! 

It doesn't happen on any phone: on my samsung galaxy (both 2 and 4) it opens immidietly, but on nexus 4 only after 4 clicks. 

Only after 4 clicks the method onPrepareOptionsMenu  is called. And 4 clicks, not a random number.

Why is that? What can I do to handle it?

EDIT: The menu is opend like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);

    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: no guessing, post your code

Comment: Are you use click listener or tap listener?

Comment: I have no idea... this is what i do:
@Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
 {
  super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainMenu.class);

  startActivity(intent);
  return true;
 }

What in my code should I show?

Comment: You seem to be trying to start a new activity when onPrepareOptionsMenu is called. This isn't a good idea. What are actually trying to do? Also its best if you edit your question and post the code there - it will be much more readable

Comment: But onPrepareOptionsMenu is only called after 4 clicks... Opening the menu like an activity can be this harmful? And yes - I want a new screen for the menu...

Comment: The menu you're trying to open is just an activity? Why not just start your application on the menu activity?

Comment: I want a new screen to open when you select menu, not a tiny bubble or something... You are welcome to download my app and tell me what can I do...